# Windows Store Apps: localized control style through resw files?

Tags: localization, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Store App that supports English and Arabic Languages.

In a page I have a localiezed Text block like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="TxtTitle" Style="{StaticResource TxtStyle}" />
```

and I have two resw files with the following structire:

- Resources/**en**/Resources.resw
- Resources/**ar**/Resources.resw

in each **resw** file I have an entry with the key **TxtTitle.Text** that has the localized text of the TextBlock.

Now I want to localize the style of text block, so I added the following entries to the resw files:

- Resources/**en**/Resources.resw" TxtTitle.Style:{StaticResource TxtStyle}
- Resources/**ar**/Resources.resw" TxtTitle.Style:{StaticResource TxtStyleAR}

then removed the Style attribute from the TextBlock in my page.

The problem is that the application crashes, what can be wrong here ?

Comment: The issue seems to me to be that the XAML is converting the string into a static resource at compile-time, not run-time. Does it only crash in one language versus the other? Or both? If both, then what I'd probably do is use a converter to set the style. Pass in the TextBlock itself as a parameter and set it in the converter (retrieving from the App.Resources based on the Uid as a key).

Comment: Why not to use PCL (portable class library) for localization? It can be used on Windows 8 and Windows Phone 7/8. It's visible at runtime in xaml and overall better.

Comment: @NateDiamond Using a converter is a valid solution, but I believe it will be too much to create a converter for each TextBox

Comment: @crea7or I'm already using a PCL for my models and ViewModels, how can I use it for localization ?

Comment: Can't you use the same style, but only update the properties in the style that needs to be localized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing and I think this will solve your issue:

In the Style, give your Setter and x:Uid and reference that one in your resource file with [X:uid].Value

```
<Style x:Key="x" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter x:Uid="blabla" Property="Text" Value="LeftToRight" />
</Style>
```

I have value in my resource file blabla.Value = "some value"

Answer (score 0):

Use [this solution](http://suchan.cz/2013/09/shared-localization-for-windows-phone-8-and-windows-8-apps-using-pcl/) to put localization into Portable Class Library. In the most cases it will allow you to avoid such problems with localization in resources.

Comment: Thanks for the useful solution, it's nice but I've already added my resources files in the Windows project, I'll try your approach next time.